# Error on deserializing data from an restApi response to an class object in java?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization

i am trying to deserialize this data from the api

```
          [{
             "id":1,
              "title":"Book of arts",
              "Author":"Helena"
         }]     
     Response response = 
   RestApiHandler.sendParametricRequest("GET",url,paramsMap,dataMap);
```

How can i deserialise this to a class object in java?.

```
      public class PostData{
               public int id;
               public String title;
               public String author;
               public int getId() {
               return id;
              }

         public void setId(int id) {
               this.id = id;
         } 
           public String getTitle() {
              return title;
            }

         public void setTitle(String title) {
               this.title = title;
         }
         public String getAuthor() {
              return author;
            }

         public void setAuthor(String author) {
               this.author = author;
         }
         }
```

i have tried this ,
PostData postData = response.as(PostData.class);
System.out.println(postData.getAuthor());
Its giving me errors. Please help, Tia

Comment: Which library are you using?
Generally speaking you can deserialize using [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or similar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the json str from response object?  i feel this is a str convert to object problem

the following code use jackson

```
    String jsonStr = "other object json";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TargetObject targetObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, TargetObject.class);
```

Comment: i have tried this, i am getting an error here, can you able to tell me how can i printout a value for the class please, thanks

Comment: you can override the toString method for your entity class

Comment: just get it done PostData post = response.as(PostData[].class); . its working, thanks